# How to call another python file with arguments and --flags

Tags: python, scripting

So, I have a script which uses three flags, two input and one output file. However I would like to write a script that calls this script and replaces one or more of the input files with each file from a specified subdirectory

So far I have imported sys and listdir, so my current plan is to use sys to get an argument for the folder that i want to have the files from and use listdir to have an easy way to iterate through the filenames and call each one individually with that other script i mentioned.

However I dont know how to call the script from inside my current file together with the flags (e.g. script.py --content ./contentfolder/content.jpg ...) and execute the entire batch.

```
from os import listdir
import sys 

def main():
    script = sys.argv[0]
    contentfolder = sys.argv[1]
    for file in listdir(contentfolder):
        #call script --content file --input2 "filename" --output "out" ...     
main()
```

I'm quite new to python scripts so didnt get very far yet, but I also couldnt find anything useful with google (could be looking for the wrong keywords maybe?)

Comment: What is the script you're calling doing? You can just import the module and call the methods it's calling on those files directly.

Comment: I am not 100% sure tbh. It is an open sourced code that performs a kind of image transformation on one picture and i essentially just want to write a script to let it run that one command on a range of pictures instead of re-typing it 1k times. 
So I'm not very familiar with what it calls when.